# Create side by side plot with raw data

Tags: python

I have a raw data set of no. of items produced per day, per shift:

```
x = [{'day' : 1, 'shift' : 1, 'count':3}, 
    {'day' : 1, 'shift' : 2, 'count':5}, 
    {'day' : 1, 'shift' : 3, 'count':7}, 
    {'day' : 2, 'shift' : 1, 'count':2}, 
    {'day' : 2, 'shift' : 2, 'count':4},
    {'day' : 2, 'shift' : 3, 'count':6},]
x_df = pd.DataFrame(x)
x_df = x_df[['day', 'shift', 'count']]
```

I would like to plot a daily chart with the counts per shift placed side by side. I think the first thing to do is to make the `day` the x-axis, and `shift_1` as 1 column, `shift_2` as 1 column and `shift_3` as another column. Is there an easy way in pandas to do this?

Comment: is matplotlib ok?

Comment: yes matplotlib is ok

Answer (score 1):

For a scatter plot this should work

```
import pylab
import pandas as pd

x = [{'day' : 1, 'shift' : 1, 'count':3}, 
    {'day' : 1, 'shift' : 2, 'count':5}, 
    {'day' : 1, 'shift' : 3, 'count':7}, 
    {'day' : 2, 'shift' : 1, 'count':2}, 
    {'day' : 2, 'shift' : 2, 'count':4},
    {'day' : 2, 'shift' : 3, 'count':6},]
x_df = pd.DataFrame(x)
x_df = x_df[['day', 'shift', 'count']]


for s in x_df['shift'].unique(): 
    x = x_df[x_df['shift'] == s]
    pylab.plot(x['day'],x['count'],label="shift %i" %s)
pylab.legend(loc='best')
pylab.ylabel("count")
pylab.xlabel("day")
```

output

[image]

for a clustered bar chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *
x = [{'day' : 1, 'shift' : 1, 'count':3}, 
    {'day' : 1, 'shift' : 2, 'count':5}, 
    {'day' : 1, 'shift' : 3, 'count':7}, 
    {'day' : 2, 'shift' : 1, 'count':2}, 
    {'day' : 2, 'shift' : 2, 'count':4},
    {'day' : 2, 'shift' : 3, 'count':6},]
x_df = pd.DataFrame(x)
x_df = x_df[['day', 'shift', 'count']]

w = .3 #set width of bar
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
shifts = x_df['shift'].unique()

for s in shifts: 
    x = x_df[x_df['shift'] == s]
    counts = array(x['count'])
    inds = arange(len(counts))
    plt.bar(inds*w*1.1+s,counts,w)

#pretty up xaxis
ax.set_xticks(shifts+w*max(inds)/2)
ax.set_xticklabels(shifts)
plt.ylabel("count")
plt.xlabel("shift")
```

output
[image]

to adjust bar chat see manual here:
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/units/bar_unit_demo.html

Comment: hi, i'm sorry i was looking for a bar chart, with the x-axis having shift 1, shift 2, shift 3, and in each cluster of bars there's day 1 and day 2 data. this way i can see how similar are the counts per day, in each shift.

Comment: Now I understand. You want it clustered by shift first, then day.

Comment: @bryansis2010 does that do it?